# get_terms returns array starting at 4

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am using get terms to return a list of terms within a custom taxonomy.  It's returning an array but it starts at index 4.

How do I get it to start at 0 like normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `get_terms` like this:

```
var_dump(get_terms('category',array('hide_empty'=>false)));
```

And then like this:

```
var_dump(get_terms('category'));
```

You should be able to infer what is happening. The first should return the zero based array you expect, with neatly numbered keys. The second does not. The only difference being the `hide_empty` argument.

If you really must have a zero based array just pass the results though PHP's `array_values`:

```
var_dump(array_values(get_terms('category')));
```